# Android equivalent of Core spotlight

Tags: android, ios, search

Is there any library in android which is similar to iOS core spotlight framework. I searched a lot I found some Java libraries which can provide search. Is there any pure android based solutions !?

Answer (score 0):

Android's OS-level search functionality is different than iOS'. Rather than providing an OS-level way to search data across multiple apps, it supports a couple of different types of functionality:

- [Quick Search Box search suggestions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-custom-suggestions.html#QSB) in which an Activity can expose an intent for searching. Android documents [the search config definition](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/searchable-config.html).
- [indexing app content](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-indexing/). This is probably the most similar to iOS's spotlight search, especially considering the disclaimer:

> None of the user’s personal content is uploaded to Google servers, and it only remains on the device while the app is installed. Developers can specify what content, if any, is shared across a user's devices via Google servers. However, aggregated statistics about apps' usage of App Indexing and other system health information may be uploaded to Google servers.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Android don't have anymore this feature, I can't find this feature on the new released Android 10. Only the Samsung Galaxy seems to have this feature in the world of Androids, this is very sad.