# Android - Spotlight search

Tags: android, spotlight

I'm new in android development and I was wondering if there is a spotlight search in android like the one in iOS?
if so, where I could find some tutorials for that?
I have tried to google it but I couldn't find any library that supports it. and I had found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43526162/android-equivalent-of-core-spotlight) but unfortunately there are no answers.

Answer (score 1):

Android's OS-level search functionality is a bit more piecemeal than iOS'. It supports a couple of different types of functionality:

- [Quick Search Box search suggestions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-custom-suggestions.html#QSB) in which an Activity can expose an intent for searching. Android documents [the search config definition](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/searchable-config.html).
- [indexing app content](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-indexing/). This is probably the most similar to iOS's spotlight search, especially considering the disclaimer:

> None of the user’s personal content is uploaded to Google servers, and it only remains on the device while the app is installed. Developers can specify what content, if any, is shared across a user's devices via Google servers. However, aggregated statistics about apps' usage of App Indexing and other system health information may be uploaded to Google servers.